# django accessing filter results by index doesnt save it to models

Tags: django, django-models

Model:

```
class faqs(models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 question=models.TextField()
 answer=models.TextField()
 category=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
 frequency=models.IntegerField(max_length=10, blank = True, null = True)
 class Meta:
    db_table='faqs'
```

The folloing does'nt save it to DB,

```
s=faqs.objects.filter(id=1)
s[0].id=111
s[0].save()
```

But this saves the upadted value to DB,

```
s=faqs.objects.filter(id=1)[0]
s.id=111
s.save()
```

Why is not django not allowing to save values via the first method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that each time you slice the queryset, Django hits the database and creates a *new* instance. So the instance you set the `id` on is not the same instance as the one you call `save()` on - remember that Django instances do not have identity, and that separate objects that refer to the same database row don't share anything.

You can see what's happening if you examine the database queries: you'll see that no queries are executed for the first line, the filter. A SELECT is executed for the second line - but it only gets one instance, using a LIMIT 1. And an identical SELECT is executed for the third line, giving you a completely new instance.

You've already seen one way round this. The other way is to force the entire queryset to be executed after the `filter`, but calling `list` on the result.

Comment: I know that query set evaluation are lazy...but still not clear.why accessing a list does'nt save to DB?

Comment: Why type(s[0]) and type(s) gives the same result?

Comment: For your first question, I don't know how I can make it any clearer. You slice the queryset and get an instance, modify it, then *throw it away*. Then you get a *new* instance, and save it: but that instance hasn't changed. For your second question, they don't.

Answer (score -1):

Possible because [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). Which means that when you access an item from a queryset without initiating it, it does not update the queryset, as it  is a `queryset item`  not a real instance of a model.

Fix:

```
s = faqs.objects.filter(id=1)
obj = s[0]
obj.id=111
obj.save()
```

Comment: Not quite. It's a perfectly real instance of a model, but you get a new instance each time. See my answer.